# Gazebo 11 for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gazebo-11, gazebo-10, ubuntu-20.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Congrats on the Gazebo 11 release. I note on the project status page that Ubuntu F is listed as a supported platform:

http://gazebosim.org/#status

However, there don't seem to be packages available for `gazebo11` or its dependencies available at `packages.osrfoundation.org`. Is there a planned timeline for Focal packages to be made available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24413/gazebo-11-for-ubuntu-20.04?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2020-02-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Mike:

We usually don't release any version into any platform still not released officially. That said we would like to see official Ubuntu package for Gazebo11 (work in progress). In any case the plan is to release stable package as soon as Ubuntu launches the release officially (April 2020).

In this case, for the LTS, we can create a prerelease to see if things are working as expected to speed up the testing before the official release and have all ready to make the stable release for it. Early in March (after the introduction of new packages or major versions) would be a good time for it.

**Update:** focal/amd64 for gazebo11 is now in the osrfoundation.org repositories.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on 2020-02-05**:
Upstream looks like it'll get Gazebo 9.6 again, based on libsdformat6 and all the other dependencies being in place for it (it's also still 9.6 in the current sid).

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on 2020-02-05**:
Alternatively, are there updated instructions anywhere for building gz11 sanely from source using a workspace builder like catkin_tools or colcon? The "from source" page on the Gazebo wiki seems to still assume packages exist for all the first-tier dependencies (ignition-*, sdformat, etc).

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2020-02-06**:
gazebo9 is still the version inside Debian/Ubuntu yes. To build gz11 from source in a ROS friendly workspace probably this file from gazebodistro can help you: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebodistro/src/default/gazebo11.yaml . Try using the vcs and colcon, it should work.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on 2020-02-07**:
Perfect, that's just what I was looking for, thanks— I had been trying with the master branches of everything and was ending up in a complete dependency snarl.

**Comment by [aposhian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46930/aposhian/) on 2021-05-05**:
I cannot find packages for focal in https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/. Could you provide a link?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2021-05-07**:
This ones https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/dists/focal/ ?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2021-05-07**:
These ones https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/dists/focal/ ?